# Hiding a div element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, visibility

Following is the code where I display matched user input in the div but I want to hide the div when there is no match for user input. I can't seem to do it with the following code:

HTML code:

```
 <input id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Enter your filter text here.." onkeyup = "test()" />

 <div id="lc">  <p id='placeholder'> </p>  </div>
```

JS code:

```
 // JavaScript Document

 s1= new String()
 s2= new String()
 var myArray = new Array();

 myArray[0] = "Football";
 myArray[1] = "Baseball";
 myArray[2] = "Cricket";
 myArray[3] = "Hockey";
 myArray[4] = "Basketball";
 myArray[5] = "Shooting";

 function test()
 {
 s1 = document.getElementById('filter').value;
 var myRegex = new RegExp((s1),"ig");
  arraysearch(myRegex);
  }

 function arraysearch(myRegex)
 {
  document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML=""; 
for(i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
{ 
if (myArray[i].match(myRegex))
{ 
   document.getElementById('lc').style.visibility='visible';
   document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML += myArray[i] + "<br/>";
}
    else
    {
   document.getElementById('lc').style.visibility='hidden';
    }
}

    }
```

Comment: first add some alerts and try to see where exactly is the code going wrong. Start the javascript console to see errors.

Comment: If you are using older versions of IE. Strictly declare variables using var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are a powerful tool but using them for so trivial a job is often troublesome.First you are using a direct input as regular expression which is never so good.

I copied your code and analyzed the logic you are making many many **errors**

```
for(i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
{ 
if (myArray[i].match(myRegex))
{ 
   document.getElementById('lc').style.visibility='visible';
   document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML += myArray[i] + "<br/>";
}
    else
    {
   document.getElementById('lc').style.visibility='hidden';
    }
```

consider your code above, if I enter football, it matches with football, and football is shown. *Next it checks for baseball which does not match and visibility changes to hidden!!*

**Better logic**

1.Check what strings match, and add them to the division.

2.**Check how many strings have matched**, if none, change visibility to hidden.

You are using regular expressions when this actully can be achieved easily with indexOf();

**these are pure logical errors**

Comment: Yes, just figured the dumb mistake. Added a flag to check if any matches were found. Works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

consider using jquery.  (with a little http://underscorejs.org/ for utility)

```
var myArray = ["Football", "Baseball", "Cricket","Hockey", "Basketball", "Shooting"]

$("#filter").keyup(function() {
  if(_.include(myArray, $(this).val()) { 
    $('#lc').show()
  } else {
    $('#lc').hide() 
  }
}
```